# Not able to alert the value of Select value

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am tying to alert the value of namesEmp variable and i get this Ljava.lang.String;@3433205b as result.

my javacsript:

```
function getNames(names) {       
           var namesEmp = "";  
           var namesEmpText = "";
           for(i=0;i<names.length;i++) {               
                    if(names.options[i].selected) {             
                          namesEmp = names.options[i].value;  
                          namesEmpText = names.options[i].text;                         
                            alert(namesEmp); 
                            alert(namesEmpText);  
                    }
            }        
  }
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<tr  style="position:relative;left:19;top:1;display:none;">
        <td style="position:relative;top:1;text-align:right;">Country:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="namePay" name="namesPay" onChange="setTimeout('getNames(f.name)',1);">
                <%
                String namesDesc = "";
                if(namesList.size()>0){                 
                        for(int i=0;i<namesList.size();i++){
                             String[] namesValues = ((String)namesList.get(i)).split("~");                           
                             NamesText = namesValues[0];                              
                %> 
                    <option value="<%=namesValues%>"><%=NamesText%>                    
                        <%}
                      }%>

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

When I alert namesEmpText, i get the the correct result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect to get? Why?

Comment: `setTimeout('getNames(f.name)',1);` - where is `f` defined?

Comment: I want the value of the Emp. i.e. "James". i do get the "James for namesEmpText. but for namesEmp i get "Ljava.lang.String;@3433205b ".

Comment: It appears you're given the server-side code that generates the JavaScript. Can you also show us the generated client-side code? (e.g., press `Ctrl+U` to View Source in your browser) I've tagged this question `[jsp]`; please correct me if that's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
<option value="<%=namesValues%>"><%=NamesText%>
                  ^
```

You are trying to render the Java *object* `namesValues` (a string array), as a select option value. The JVM doesn't know how to automatically convert an array to a string, so it renders the type name for it instead. Did you mean to include an indexer to that array? For example:

```
<option value="<%=namesValues[1]%>"><%=namesValues[0]%>
```

Comment: how do I covert string array to string. I do need indexer for namesValues.